# How to include posts with custom post status in the sitemap with Yoast SEO?

Tags: wordpress, yoast

I created a custom post status `archived` with the `register_post_status` function. 
I just realized that the plugin Yoast SEO, doesn't take it in the sitemap..Only those in publish.

How to include custom post status in the sitemap ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yoast SEO** implement a new filter in the 11.2 version to handle this

Here's the way to do this :

```
function yoast_add_custom_status( $post_statuses) {
    // var_dump($post_statuses);die();
    $post_statuses = array( 'publish','YOUR_CUSTOM_STATUS' ); //add your custom statuses
  return $post_statuses;
}
add_filter( 'wpseo_sitemap_post_statuses', 'yoast_add_custom_status');
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for me. It simply says "Website is having technical problems." :( Any solution?

Comment: @Pedro remove the 2nd argument